# Could not reflect CSS for PDF on Gitbook

Tags: html, css, git, pdf, gitbook

I could change design my Gitbook website with my CSS.
However, I didn't understand applying CSS to PDF.

When I used same CSS for PDF as CSS for website, results are not same.
I thought CSS for PDF does not seem working fine.

I wrote `book.json` as follows.

```json
"plugins": ["styles-sass", "image-captions"],
"styles": {
    "website": "styles/website.scss",
    "pdf": "styles/pdf.scss"
}
```

and `pdf.scss` is as follows.

```css
.book {
    .book-body {
        .page-wrapper {
            .page-inner {
                section.normal {
                    h1 {
                        text-align: center;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please tell me about that this operation is correct.
Or if you have any sample about `pdf.css`, please tell me.

Comment: styling PDF documents with CSS? That's new to me

Comment: and I think when you link a CSS file it has to be the generated one (dot CSS) not a SASS file, SASS files are not compiled and I don't think the browser would understand them AFAIK

Comment: @Aziz Yes, Gitbook supports styling PDF with CSS. You can see https://help.gitbook.com/styling/book.html. However I didn't understand how to write it. I think pdf.css is not same as website.css.
SASS file can be compiled into CSS automatically when I upload files to Gitbook. I think it's no problem to use SASS file.

Comment: Ok I get it now. yes apparently you can use a plugin that allows SASS without complaining, which is already in your code. Right, I believe you're dealing with the CSS for print media (@media print). It seems styling for print medium right now is very limited to basic CSS and will never look exactly like a website viewed on a screen for obvious reasons. I'd advise you to research "CSS for print limitation"

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem.
Gitbook refers  `/home/<UserName>/.gitbook/versions/2.6.7/theme/assets/ebook/pdf.css` in default settings.
Then, I found `.section.toc>h1{text-align:center;}` in this file.
So I wrote `style/pdf.scss` as follows, and it works fine.

```css
.section {
    &.toc {
        >h1 {
            text-align:right;
        }
    }
}
```

If above stylesheet is used, table contents title is aligned right.
And other style will be set with same way.

Thank you!!